# Which learning model should I use to find out the most relevant applicants?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

Let say for one job application we received 10,000 applications. But after a long exercise we found only 10 resumes are relevant fit. Which ML model would be the right choice to determine the most relevant candidates?

Comment: Why can't you apply the same algorithm you used to cull the 10,000 applicants to 10?

Comment: @Emre May be that "long exercise" is manually checking each one of them and separating :D

Comment: @Kiritee Yes that is why we are thinking to come up with Machine learning model here.

Comment: @Advika It is not models always, it is all about the features you are going to supply to the model/estimator. Do you have those features with you?

Comment: @Kiritee . Yes, we have listed down the features but still figuring out which model would be most suitable. For example KNN or some retrieval model like BM25.